# Datatable not updated after delete entity-relationship

Tags: jsf, primefaces

i have the following issue:
I have a table which was created by Primefaces. In this table i show the elements of a @OneToMany relationship. The user clicks a name and the table show the releationship of this customer. This works fine. But - the user should delete single elements from the table. So each entry has a delete button. Now the problem:
If i click on a button the entry in the database is delete correctly but the update of my form shows always the entry. So what must i change?

```
    <p:dataTable value="#{hauptBean.listeRisikotraeger.risikotraeger}"
                        var="tr" id="tab" styleClass="tabelle"
                        emptyMessage="Keine Risikoträger definiert"
                        rendered="#{not empty hauptBean.standardSelektion and(not empty hauptBean.listeRisikotraeger.risikotraeger and(!hauptBean.aenderung))}">
                        <p:column headerText="Risikoträger">
                            <h:outputText value="#{tr.name}" />
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column width="70">
                            <p:commandButton value="löschen"
                                actionListener="#{hauptBean.eintragLoeschen(tr)}"
                                update="@form" />
                        </p:column>
                    </p:dataTable>
```

The first Entity

```
@Entity
public class Risikobereich implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;
private String risikobereich;

@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name="ri_id", referencedColumnName="id")    
private List<Risikotraeger> risikotraeger;

[GETTER/SETTER]
```

And the entity relationship:

```
@Entity
public class Risikotraeger implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id_risiko;

private String name;
private String abstraktesRisiko;

[GETTER/SETTER]
```

**EDIT**

This is my Session Bean, which does all the stuff in the background:

```
@Override
public boolean loeschen(Risikotraeger traeger) {

    boolean erfolgreich = false;

    em.remove(em.merge(traeger));

    erfolgreich = true;

    return erfolgreich;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you reloaded `listeRisikotraeger` respectively removed the record in it?

A short suggestion: Why do you update your `@form` after pressing the delete button instead of the datatable directly? If there are other components next to the datatable to update, I would recommend, to define an ID on each component and refer to them. So you can reduce the scope of the page elements which should be updated. For example: `<p:datatable id=tableRisikotraeger .../>` ... `<p:commandButton value="löschen" update="tableRisikotraeger" .../>`

Comment: Yes i have tried it the same way...but still dosen't work. The Problem is, that the table not refresh the new way.

Comment: What do you mean with "the new way"? Can you tell me which scope your `hauptBean` has?

Comment: It has the SessionScope